# how to make SIMBL base plugin Package file?

Tags: installation, packagemaker, simbl

I have created a SIMBL based plugin which runs on safari but i am not able to make package file of my plugin through package maker, 
Following step i am doing.
1: in Package make set the my plugin bundle file path "library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins".
2: Finish the pkg.

Try to install pkg file and it installs success fully and place my plugin in the target location.

But when i open the Safari my plugin does not come.

And when i compile my code and run plugin comes on safari.

Please help how can i make the package file?

Thanks
Amit Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my package installer (a bundle that installs SIMBL and copies a Dictionary.app plugin into *.../SIMBL/Plugins* folder), that might solve you problem. The source is at https://github.com/pooriaazimi/BetterDictionary (`Installer.pmdoc` in the *Installer* folder).